# Twig active navbar item

Tags: php, twig

in index.php

```
switch($page){
    case 'home':
        echo $twig->render('home.twig');
        break;
    case 'iletisim':
        echo $twig->render('iletisim.twig');
        break;
    case 'hakkimizda':
        echo $twig->render('hakkimizda.twig');
```

in layout.twig

```
                <nav id="primary-menu" class="serif normal">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="current"><a href="index.php?p=home"><div>Ana Sayfa</div></a></li>      
                        <li><a href="index.php?p=hakkimizda"><div>Hakkımızda</div></a></li>                     
                        <li><a href="index.php?p=konaklama"><div>Konaklama</div></a>
                        </li>                            
                        <li><a href="#"><div>Çocuk &amp; Aile</div></a>
                            <ul>                               
                                <li><a href="index.php?p=oyun_alanlari"><div>Oyun Alanları</div></a></li>                                          
                                <li><a href="index.php?p=piknik_alanlari"><div>Piknik Alanları</div></a></li>                                 
                            </ul>                            


                    </ul>
                </nav><!-- #primary-menu end -->
```

I want to be active in the navbar when the page changes, how can I do it

Comment: since you using "p" parameter to render some view you could also use that to make link active.

Comment: doydoy44 ' s answer is worked, thanks for your answer ArtOsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

in index.php

```
switch($page){
    case 'home':
        echo $twig->render('home.twig', ['current' => 'home']);
        break;
    case 'iletisim':
        echo $twig->render('iletisim.twig', ['current' => 'iletisim']);
        break;
    case 'hakkimizda':
        echo $twig->render('hakkimizda.twig', ['current' => 'hakkimizda']);
    ....
```

and in layout.twig

```
<nav id="primary-menu" class="serif normal">
    <ul>
        <li {{ (current == 'home') ? 'class="current"' : '' }}><a href="index.php?p=home"><div>Ana Sayfa</div></a></li>      
        <li {{ (current == 'hakkimizda') ? 'class="current"' : '' }}><a href="index.php?p=hakkimizda"><div>Hakkımızda</div></a></li>                     
        <li {{ (current == 'konaklama') ? 'class="current"' : '' }}><a href="index.php?p=konaklama"><div>Konaklama</div></a></li>                            
...
```

Of course, you an improve this way.